# What harmonic idea is being used in Measures 9-12 and 17-19 in "Recuerdos De La Alhambra? "

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-progressions, classical-music, analysis

I have done some harmonic analysis on Francisco Tárrega's “Recuerdos De La Alhambra”, as you can see below. Most of it makes sense to me, but there are sections in measures 9-12 and 17-19 that the chords don't move in a way that makes sense to me. Can someone please explain to me the harmonic theory there?

[image: measures 1–8]

[image: measures 9–20]

Comment: A harmonic analysis should tell a "big picture," as well as perhaps small pictures, and isn't just about finding a chord name for every moment, but about finding the role of a group of notes. Measures 9 and 10 both start with an F chord. We haven't really "gone anywhere" in the last beat of m 9; you could think of it as "still an F," but with the two passing tones of B and G. The last beat of m. 10 is another matter though, and I'm still thinking about it...

Comment: I should point out that I am a plectrum player, so in a few spots I have written an incorrect inversion, but it is because I am using a chord shape that would allow me to strum the guitar and sound only the needed notes. In those cases the bass note serves to deaden a string, but I do not sound it for this song. So, for example, I play the first E7 in the song with my ring finger on G# on string 6, to practice getting into that position.

Comment: Noted, though I assume the point of your analysis is to better understand that harmonic "big picture." Actual implementation often leaves out (or adds) a note, but the benefit of analysis to performance is knowing where we're going and why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Measures 9 – 12

Measure 9 and the first two beats of Measure 10 are just one long F major chord. The apparent CM7 is just a **passing chord**, meaning that it serves the purposes of connecting the harmonies on either side but isn't itself considered as affecting the harmony.

The G7/D chord in measure 10 is better analyzed as a Bdim/D chord. It's use here is as a **common-tone chord**. It shares the note B with the E chord that's coming up. For more information see [A chord progression from Leavitt: how to analyze the diminished chord](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/104304/70803)

Measure 11 is analyzed as an E chord (in root position, not /G#). The A at the beginning of the measure is an **accented passing tone**, delaying the arrival of the G#. It also could be viewed as a sort of suspension of the A from measure 10. If you really want to name it as a chord, it would be Esus4.

Measure 12 is an E7 leading back to A in Measure 13. The initial chord in Measure 13 is just A. The b9 is an **accented upper neighbor**, just there for color and not considered part of the overall harmonic analysis.

#### Measures 17 – 19

Measure 17 is still a Dm chord, continued from Measure 16. The E is another accented passing tone, as in Measure 11. The B is also serving a primarily melodic function rather than a harmonic one, but you could call the chord Dm6 if you want.

Measure 18 contains an Faug6 chord. The purpose of the chord is that the F resolves down to E, and the D# resolves up to E. (The expected resolution of an F7 chord would be to a Bb chord, with the Eb resolving down to D). "Augmented sixth chords" are explained in various posts on this site: for example, [How does this chord work in the progression?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/109696/70803).

Measure 19 is all one E chord, with an accented passing tone C on the first beat.